# Keeping data together in spark based on cassandra table partition key

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

When loading data from Cassandra table, a spark partition represents all rows with same partition key. However, when I create data in spark with same partition key and re-partitioning the new RDD  using .repartitionByCassandraReplica(..) method, it ends up in a different spark partition? How do I achieve consistent partitions in spark using the partition-scheme defined by the Spark-Cassandra connector?

> Links to download CQL and Spark job code that I tested

- [.CQL with the keyspace and table schema](https://sarmathi.blob.core.windows.net/spark/test.cql).
- [Spark job](https://sarmathi.blob.core.windows.net/spark/CassandraConnectorTest.java) and other classes.

> Version and other information

- Spark : 1.3
- Cassandra : 2.1
- Connector : 1.3.1
- Spark nodes (5) and Cass* cluster nodes (4) runs in different data centers

> Code extract. Download code using above links for more details

**Step 1 : Loads data into 8 spark partitions**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
CassandraTableScanJavaRDD<TestTable> tableRdd = javaFunctions(conf)
 .cassandraTable("testkeyspace", "testtable", mapRowTo(TestTable.class, map));
```

**Step 2 : Repartition data into 8 partitions**

```
.repartitionByCassandraReplica(
        "testkeyspace",
        "testtable",
        partitionNumPerHost,
        someColumns("id"),
        mapToRow(TestTable.class, map));
```

**Step 3: Print partition id and values for both rdds**

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(...{
@Override
 public Iterator<String> call(..) throws Exception {
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add("PartitionId-" + integer);

 while (itr.hasNext()) {
    TestTable value = itr.next();
    list.add(Integer.toString(value.getId()));
 }
 return list.iterator();
}
}, true).collect();
```

**Step 4 : Snapshot of results printed on Partition 1. Different for both Rdds but expect to be same**

Load Rdd values

```
----------------------------
Table load - PartitionId -1
----------------------------
15
22

--------------------------------------
Repartitioned values - PartitionId -1
--------------------------------------
33
16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repartition by Cassandra replica does not deterministically place keys. There is a ticket currently to change that.

https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/SPARKC/issues/SPARKC-278

A workaround now is to set the Partitionspernode parameter to 1.

Comment: Thanks. Any date on when this feature would arrive? This work around would restrict us to have only few partitions in spark, which is not ideal.

Comment: I have one more related question. The readConf object passed to .cassandraTable(..) takes a flat number of total spark partitions whereas the .repartitionByCassandraReplica(..) takes partition per Cassandra node. What is the recommendation to keep the same number of total partitions in both API's.